# Prevent Specflow Step Parameter Displaying In Specflow Report i.e. 'password'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I have a bunch of Specflow step definitions that use parameters for 'Username' and 'Password'.

When the steps are displayed in the Specflow Report it renders the passed in values. It's not usually an issue as it's run on test environments and the report is only emailed to selected individuals...However, the output is stored locally and I want to move it to a more accessible location (in case I'm not available)...thus the need to hide the values.

I want to be able to hash specific parameters after using them. So the Default Specflow report doesn't show the real values.

I already have a potential workaround by using values stored in a JSON file that overrides the step parameters...and from trial and error I know this approach does not display the JSON values...instead the Specflow Report keeps the values originally used in the Feature File.

Feature scenario example:

```
Scenario: As a registered user I can log in with a valid email and password
Given I am on the Home page
When I click the Sign In option
Then The login page is displayed
When I enter valid login details and submit 'tester@test.co.uk', 'Password1!'
Then I am logged in
And The Sign In display name is displayed in the header 'Tester McTestFace'
```

Step Definition example:

```
[When(@"I enter valid login details and submit '(.*)', '(.*)'")]
    public void WhenIEnterValidLoginDetailsAndSubmit(string email, string password)
    {
        PageAction.CompleteLoginForm(email, password);
    }
```

This then gets passed to the WebDriver to do the applicable actions

My Json override method is my only option at the moment but hopefully there is some really easy built in Specflow functionality that can hash the values (yet to find any documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the passwords for each e-mail in the ScenarioContext, then just reference the e-mail address from the scenario.

Your step definition becomes:

```cs
[Binding]
public class LoginSteps
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    public LoginSteps(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;

        scenario.Set("Password1", "email1");
        scenario.Set("Password2", "email2");
        ...
        scenario.Set("PasswordN", "emailN");
    }

    [When(@"I log in as '(.*)'")]
    public void WhenILogInAs(string email)
    {
        PageAction.CompleteLoginForm(email, scenario.Get(email));
    }
}
```

And your scenario becomes:

```
Scenario: As a registered user I can log in with a valid email and password
    Given I am on the Home page
    When I click the Sign In option
    Then The login page is displayed
    When I log in as 'tester@test.co.uk'
    Then I am logged in
    And The Sign In display name is displayed in the header 'Tester McTestFace'
```

Comment: thanks. I'll look in to this method. Will require a bit of rework in my step and feature files. I'm guessing with the Scenario.Set methods you can essentially store unlimited combinations and you it 'matches' the email passed in to the associated, paired password?

Comment: @Scott: That is correct. It's like a bag of data you can pass around from step to step.

Comment: sorted my issue. Thanks for this